# imagemagic: stacking of the images using convert and montage

Tags: image, imagemagick

My bash script uses convert of the image magic to stack horizontally two types of the images producing 2xN multi-image chart:

```
convert  \( "${output}/type1*.png" -append \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" -append \) +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/summary.png
```

how would it be possible to add border of the selected dimensions between stacked images in the manner as I may do via montage -mattecolor $color_id ?

```
montage \( "${output}/type1*.png" \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" \) -geometry 800x600+1+1 -tile x2 -frame 4 -background white -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame -bordercolor white ${output}/summary.png
```

Comment: See -border Tx0, where T is some thickness you want in the horizontal direction. Use that on each image before appending. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

Comment: great thank you! and how to specify additionally the color of the border like I did it using montage -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2  ?

Comment: Put -bordercolor xxx before -border Tx0.  You should see that in the page I referenced.

Comment: thnak you ! fantastic

Comment: The -border with produce double size spacing between images, but only single size on the ends. If you want single size everywhere, see -splice at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#splice.  You will then need to add one more splice to one side of the appended result.

Comment: here is my another question about Image-magic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024912/image-magic-automatically-adding-the-filenames-of-the-stacking-images

Answer (score 0):

vertical borders between each separate sections of the type1/ type2 and a horizontal border between the both parts joined in the summary:

```
convert  \( "${output}/type1*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 -append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/summary.png
```