# image-magic: automatically adding the filenames of the stacking images

Tags: imagemagick

My bash script uses convert and montage of the Image magic to stack 2xN multi-image chart.
Convert:

```
convert  \( "${output}/type1*.png" -append \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" -append \) +append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/summary.png
```

Montage:

```
montage \( "${output}/type1*.png" \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" \) -geometry 800x600+1+1 -tile x2 -frame 4 -background white -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame -bordercolor white ${output}/summary.png
```

Would it be possible via some option to automatically add the name of the stacked images directly on each initial png file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. I made 4 randomly coloured input images, each 100x100 like this:

```
magick -size 2x2 xc: +noise random -crop 1x1 -scale 100x100 +repage type-%02d.png
```

[image]

They are named like this:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  595 11 Oct 10:35 type-00.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  594 11 Oct 10:35 type-01.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  595 11 Oct 10:35 type-02.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  595 11 Oct 10:35 type-03.png
```

---

The basic technique you need is to:

- iterate over the input images
- add a label to each one
- aggregate and pipe all the resulting individual images into `montage`

---

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in type-*png; do             
  magick "$f" -gravity South -fill black -background Plum -font "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Comic Sans MS Bold.ttf" -splice 0x18 -annotate +0+2 "$f" miff:-
done | magick montage -geometry +1+1 -tile x2 miff:- montage.png
```

[image]

---

Here's another example, but with an under-colour underneath the text and the text directly on the image and a transparent background to the montaged output:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in type-*png; do             
  magick "$f" -fill white  -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity South -annotate +0+5 "$f" miff:-
done | magick montage -background none -geometry +1+1 -tile x2 miff:- montage.png
```

[image]

Obviously you can diddle around with the colours, fonts, positioning as you wish, but the core technique remains the same.

**Note**: `MIFF:` is just *"Magick Image File Format"*, a format specific to **ImageMagick** that is guaranteed to maintain and pass on all aspects of its input - from bit-depth, through comments, through quality, through transparency down to EXIF data and beyond.

**Note**: The annotation methods I have used are derived from the excellent work by Anthony Thyssen linked [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_below) and there are many, many other examples - well worth a read.

Comment: Command 'magick' not found...    I actually uses just convert or montage in the shell without magic. what wuld be the command to add name to the png so ? :-)

Comment: `magick` is just the v7 command name. Use `convert` in place of `magick` and `montage` in place of `magick montage` if you have to persist using ancient v6.

Comment: thank you! also would it be possible to add the file name directly to the bottom of the initial image with the transparent background ( in your example the tittle is added on the purple background) thus not affecting the dimensions of the initial image ?

Comment: Of course! There are many, many ways to annotate described brilliantly by Anthony Thyssen above and below the technique I used, see https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_below

Comment: great thank you very much! in fact just a trivial question: e.g. I select to add it to the bottom with the background:  montage -label "${file_name}"  "$f" -geometry +0+0 -background Gold "${output}"/proc_${file_name2}.png       in this case it addes additional 16px in the bottom with the layer while I need that it overlaps with the existing image so do not change its dimensions

Comment: Glad it works for you. Code in the comments is unformatted and really hard to read. You should click `edit` under your question and add it in there - or ask a new one if you now want something different. Also, it is unclear whether you want the new label on each of the four input images or on top of the montaged output image, and also how it is supposed to look.

Comment: No problem! I actually just found a sollution based on the link that you sent to me. Cheers!

Comment: here is another question on the same topic you are welcome to contribute ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74029079/image-magic-conver-to-combine-and-rescale-of-the-multiple-images

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do that in Imagemagick.

Lets create images as in Mark Setchell's answer:

```
convert -size 2x2 xc: +noise random -crop 1x1 -scale 100x100 +repage type-%02d.png
```

Now we use the -label option in montage:

*(use %t if you do not want the suffix and %f if you do want the suffix on the file name)*

```
montage -label "%t" *.png -tile 2x2 -geometry +5+5 result.png
```

[image]

Or

```
montage -label "%t" *.png -tile 2x2 -geometry +5+5 result2.png
```

[image]