# image-magic: convert to combine and rescale of the multiple images

Tags: imagemagick

I use convert to stack the pair of 2 type of the image in horizontal dimension obtaining Nx2 chart

```
convert  \( "${output}/type1*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 +append \) \( type2*.png" -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 0x2 +append \) -bordercolor lightgoldenrod2 -border 2x0 -append -background white -alpha deactivate ${output}/summary.png
```

since the dimension of the type2 (600x600 image is less then the type 1 (800x600), there is a mismatch in the produced grid. Is it possible to centalize and autoscale smaller images (600x600) to 800x600 making white background on the expanded sites in order to align it with the bigger image in the table.
I've been able to achive it only via Montage -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame that produce very thick frame:

```
montage \( "${output}/type1*.png" \) \( "${output}/type2*.png" \) -geometry 800x600+1+1 -tile x"${rows}" -frame 4 -background white -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame -bordercolor white ${output}/HBONDS-summary.png
```

Comment: You might do that by padding your type2 image to the same size as type1 images. See -extent at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent

Comment: i've already checked it! I did not understand completely in the case of the  -gravity center -extent 100x80 the concert will add 100 and 80 in each directions or it's new resolution ??

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. But no, it will make (crop) the width to 100 and the height to 80.  So you should use -gravity center -extent 800x600 and it will add the amount needed to get to that size (properly centered). If you want to add 100 to the left and right and 80 to the top and bottom, you would use -bordercolor some_color -border 100x80.